# Problems with detecting delay and removing it from .after() in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing a Tkinter python game - long story short it needs to be able to run at different FPS values. However, I am having trouble maintaining a consistent second length.

I have tried to make it detect lag and take it away from the .after() function:

```
def UpdatesEveryFrame():
    s = time.perf_counter()

    # Code here

    s = int((time.perf_counter()  - s)*1000)
    LabelProductionTime3.after(int(1000 / fps) - s, UpdatesEveryFrame)
```

However, this is unsuccessful. It seems to create an accurate value in milliseconds (usually around 15) but this does not make an accurate second delay. I have tried replacing `perf_counter()` with `time()` but this has the same effect.

Because of what the game is based upon, it is essential that there is an accurate second delay. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: I think you're only taking into account the time taken by `# Code here`. You should also take into account what `tkinter` is up to in its `mainloop()`.

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for the tip, but the `time.monotonic_ms()` (see answer) worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal here is precision, then perhaps you should try the [`time.perf_counter_ns`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter_ns) method of the time module, it specifically is made to be more precise than [`time.perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter), and gives time in nanoseconds, further if the time has to be converted back into seconds, it can be done using unit conversion.

Further, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) of time.perf_counter method mentions this as well -:

> Use perf_counter_ns() to avoid the precision loss caused by the float
> type.

```
def UpdatesEveryFrame():
    s = time.perf_counter_ns()/(10 ** 9) # used perf_counter_ns, divided by (10 ** 9) to convert to seconds.

    # Code here

    s = int((time.perf_counter_ns()/(10 ** 9) - s)*1000) # used perf_counter_ns, divided by (10 ** 9) to convert to seconds.
    LabelProductionTime3.after(int(1000 / fps) - s, UpdatesEveryFrame)
```

---

**EDIT:**
There also exists [`time.monotonic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic) method, designed specifically to measure the time elapsed between two consecutive calls, it returns time in fractional seconds similar to `time.perf_counter`, so no changes have to be made in the current code except the name of the function itself.

```
def UpdatesEveryFrame():
    s = time.monotonic() # Changed method name.

    # Code here

    s = int((time.monotonic()  - s)*1000)
    LabelProductionTime3.after(int(1000 / fps) - s, UpdatesEveryFrame) # Changed method name.
```

Further, similar to the method `time.perf_counter_ns` available as a more precise version of `time.perf_counter`, there also exists a more precise version of the `time.monotonic` method that returns time in nanoseconds and functions similar to `time.monotonic`, namely [`time.monotonic_ns`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic_ns).

Comment: Hi. Precision isn't the problem here - it's just not getting it right. I don't mind it being out by a couple of ms, but this method is out by several dozen ms. Thanks for your time though!

Comment: Oh ok, but is the same observed for the `perf_counter_ns` method as well?

Comment: and have you tried [`time.monotonic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic) which is designed specifically to measure time intervals between two consecutive calls?

Comment: Unfortunately so. It stills thinks that 100 frames (50fps) should take 2.5 seconds.

Comment: Huh. I haven't heard of time.monotonic before. I'll give it a read now. The above comment was about perf_counter_ns.

Comment: Sure, I will add time.monotonic to the answer as well just in case any future readers read this, it might be helpful for them as well :)